# communication between OS services with c++

Tags: c++, linux, windows, service, communication

I am developing 2 Windows services, one of them will send pictures and word files to other and other service will give a string answer. That services are in same computer.

I will develop same program's Linux version also.

Which way is the best for communication between services in Linux and Windows.

By the way I am developing that services with C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're different options for your task:

1. Network. Establish TCP connection between your services, with service that asks as a client and service that answers as a server. It's possible to implement cross-platform solution using Boost.Asio or any other portable network library.
2. Shared memory. You can implement inter-process communication using shared memory. Cross-platform library: Boost.Interprocess.
3. Pipes. I don't know cross-platform library for this.

I would recommend to use TCP communication as more flexible solution.

Comment: It's not have to be cross-platform. I can implement different programs, which are doing same thing for Linux and Windows. I want to know fastest solution.

Comment: fastest solution is to implement it once, not different programs for different platforms. It's why I recommend to use a cross-platform library. Actually learning Boost.Asio can take some time if you've never used it before, but native socket-level networking is not simpler in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading up on C++ sockets. You're probably going to want to use TCP sockets, since you want to ensure that the data being transferred does so correctly.

Try checking these links out:

[Linux Sockets](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm)

[Windows Sockets](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13071/Programming-Windows-TCP-Sockets-in-C-for-the-Begin)

Answer (score 0):

You should search for [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).
There are a lot of possibilities for inter process communication. Because you are not very specific about your problem and your requirements but I would suggest to take a look at [boost::interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).

As long as you are sure that both services run on the same machine this will do it.
If you want to switch to a distributed approach you need something different.
Like [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC), [thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) or [corba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture). Just to mention some possibilities.